# Where clause to check against two columns in another table

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, where-in

I am struggling to get this answer for some reason.

I have two tables, table1 and table2 which look like this:

Table1:

```
ID   Location  Warehouse
1    London    Narnia
2    Cyprus    Metro
3    Norway    Neck
4    Paris     Triumph
```

Table2:

```
ID   Area      Code
1    London    Narnia
2    Cyprus    Metro
3    Norway    Triumph
4    Paris     Neck
```

I need to first select everything from table1 where `table1.Location` is in `table2.Area` **AND** `table1.Warehouse` is in `table2.Code` **GIVEN THAT** `table1.Location` is in `table2.Area`. I.e. I want:

```
ID   Location  Warehouse
1    London    Narnia
2    Cyprus    Metro
```

I have got to:

```
select
  1.location
, 1.warehouse
from table1 1
where 1.location in (select area from table2)
and 1.warehouse in (select code from table2)
```

But this won't work because I need the second where clause to be executed based on the first where clause holding true.

I have also tried similar queries with joins to no avail.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select t.location, t.warehouse
from table1 t
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t.location = t2.area and t.warehouse = t2.code
             );
```

I should point out that some databases support row constructors with `in`.  That allows you to do:

```
select t.location, t.warehouse
from table1 t
where(t1.location, t1.warehouse) in (select t2.area, t2.code from table2 t2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but a simple join on the two conditions would give you the result in your example:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.Location  = t2.Area 
              and t1.Warehouse = t2.Code;
```

Result:

```
| ID | Location | Warehouse |
|----|----------|-----------|
|  1 |   London |    Narnia |
|  2 |   Cyprus |     Metro |
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f264/3)

Comment: You would think that wouldn't you. But my table1 is about 10,000 lines long and the above query returns nearly a million rows..

Comment: @Johnathan If it returns a million rows the only plausible explanation is that you have a million rows matching the conditions in the second table. You could change the select to: `select distinct t1. location, t1.warehouse` to eliminate duplicates, but I would think that the answer by Gordon Linoff might be more appropriate in your case.

Comment: The second table only has 3500 rows so it is strange. I have marked the answer given by @Gordon below as it is getting the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JOIN`.
I'll design the query in a while :)

EDIT:

```
SELECT
  1.location
, 1.warehouse
FROM table1 1
JOIN table2 2 ON 1.location = 2.area AND 1.warehouse = 2.code
```

Comment: This was my initial query, but my table1 is about 10,000 lines long and the above query returns nearly a million rows and I can't get why.

Comment: Maybe because you have duplicating rows in one or both of the tables and that leads to Cartesian product.